# Issue installing Perl::LanguageServer via cpanm and cpan in WSL 2

Tags: perl, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cpan

Hi I am trying to install the perl::LanguageServer for eventual use in VS CODE. However, I getting errors when running:

```
sudo cpan install Perl::LanguageServer
```

I am very lost, it also says in here that I am using the wrong perl version for IO::AIO but I don't know if downgrading to an older version will break other things.

```
checking for gcc... x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no  <-- I have compiled C code into working executables before-
Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site]
```

/--------------------------------LOG

```
`Continue anyways?  [y] y
checking for gcc... x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site]
  MLEHMANN/IO-AIO-4.8.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- NOT OK
  MLEHMANN/AnyEvent-AIO-1.1.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory /root/.local/share/.cpan/build/AnyEvent-AIO-1.1-2
  MLEHMANN/AnyEvent-AIO-1.1.tar.gz
  Has already been prepared
Running make for M/ML/MLEHMANN/AnyEvent-AIO-1.1.tar.gz
The content of '/root/.local/share/.cpan/build/AnyEvent-AIO-1.1-2/META.yml' is not a HASH reference. Cannot use it.
Warning: Prerequisite 'IO::AIO => 3' for 'MLEHMANN/AnyEvent-AIO-1.1.tar.gz' failed when processing 'MLEHMANN/IO-AIO-4.8.tar.gz' with 'writemakefile => NO '/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site' returned status 19712'. Continuing, but chances to succeed are limited.
cp AIO.pm blib/lib/AnyEvent/AIO.pm
Manifying 1 pod document
  MLEHMANN/AnyEvent-AIO-1.1.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- OK
Running make test for MLEHMANN/AnyEvent-AIO-1.1.tar.gz
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/usr/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/00_load.t .. 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
Failed 1/1 subtests `
```

Comment: *"checking whether the C compiler works... no"* : Try to install these packages: `make gcc g++ pkg-config libperl-dev`, see https://gist.github.com/hakonhagland/15800c09d36ba8ee034ca1b962ad33e2

Comment: Thanks a ton, this worked! This guide you have made is really nice. Thank you!